# load modal content from external page in modal on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Learning/Building a login using the Bootstrap Modal, my page setup:

- homepage (login button which loads modal)
- login page (holds modal content fields & validation/logic etc)

If the login fails, I redirect the user back to the homepage and reload the modal (with error message 'details incorrect', which I've yet to do).

New to Ajax and JavaScript, but I wrote this snippet of ajax:

```
$(window).load(function(){          
$.ajax({
       url: 'login page',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(res) {
         $(res.responseText).find('div.all').each(function(){ //fetches the modal content
              $('div.modal-content').append($(this).html());
         });                    
       }           
      $('#myModal').modal('show'); //not sure if this is wrong      
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, it just loads a modal with no content at all and also breaks the login button. I'm sure it's this line of code `$('#myModal').modal('show');` is breaking it but don't know.

Also not sure if my approach is correct, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**: I've realized why the login button didn't work, I surrounded the the ajax in a if statement which will never be true. This will be replaced with if there is a login error

Comment: what is the purpose storing the modal content and validation in another page ? why not in page itself ?

Comment: just to separate things off, plus I'm learning as I'm going, doing it in this manner

Comment: can you write html of both page also